# How to implement single sign-on using kerberos authentication?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, kerberos, single-sign-on

I am implementing a project on single sign-on in asp.net using c#. I need to implement the authentication using kerberos. I searched the internet a lot but i am not getting any help. I am a newbie, please help me with any good post or tutorial on this.

Comment: It's a pain in the butt.  If this is a web app, it is more of a configuration thing than a programming thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When deploying your application in IIS on a Windows server registered into an ActiveDirectory domain, almost [all the job](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754628%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) is already done by default.

In a standard context: IE browsers running on a Windows workstation registered in the domain with the user logged in the domain too, HTTP SPNEGO negotiation happens by default (IE option is *Windows integrated authentication*).

Then your code in ASP.NET just have to [get username from User.Identity.Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user.aspx)