# ADFS authentication with windows credentials

Tags: adfs

For an existing ASP.NET MVC app, that connects to ADFS we would like to be able to use the os windows user credentials to automatically authenticate against ADFS. Do you have any suggestion how can be this achieved?

I really appreciate any input.

Comment: I don't know how to set it up for .NET (I'm a Java guy), but you could search for SPNEGO, NTLM and Kerberos. Maybe this is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371304/how-to-implement-single-sign-on-using-kerberos-authentication

Comment: Thank you for the response, I'll try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your ADFS is setup to allow IWA and your browser is correctly configured, this works OOTB. Typically, this works for domain-joined computers.

If your ADFS is set up for FBA i.e. you are coming in through the WAP (i.e. external) than you can't.

Comment: This is really helpful, I will try/check. Thank you.