# .NET Desktop (Non-web) application using SAML 2.0 SSO with a Kerberos Token

Tags: c#, single-sign-on, kerberos, saml-2.0, citrix

I've been reading a lot about that, in order to implement this for a customer. I am 100% certain I am misunderstanding something, because things just don't make sense in my mind right now.

Our customer wants to add, in an application we are making, an SSO feature. The idea is that on launch, when the program is installed on one of their customers, the application would validate the user's identity using SSO to figure out if they are allowed to run it.

The customer has an endpoint, on an intranet, that is supposed to respond to our SAML Request with a list of roles that the user has, that we check against a static list of authorized roles to know if this person has the correct permissions.

We are supposed to use a Kerberos Token. Now every single page I check online seems to say a different thing about that part. At first, I thought I had to somehow [obtain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37818333/how-to-get-service-token-from-kerberos-using-sspi) that Token and add it somewhere in the SAML POST Request.

Then, when googling how to obtain the Token, I get [more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10517700/5447158) and [more](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f463c91a-03c3-44f3-805f-7b3879c12a64/getting-an-existing-kerberos-ticket-using-c-amp-pass-to-a-webservice?forum=wcf) results saying that I don't have to, that it is done automatically, and that the endpoint knows "who" is calling.

Furthermore, [most](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27554/Authentication-in-web-services-using-C-and-Kerbero) [websites](https://community.appway.com/screen/community/blog/tickets-tokens-and-authentication-an-introduction-to-kerberos-1489941767141) are [assuming](https://blog.varonis.com/kerberos-authentication-explained/) that the caller (my application) is a Web Application, and have many steps of the tutorial playing with the Web.Config and the Servers, both of which I don't have.

Since everything I try seems to fail, and since I don't have control over the endpoint to check how it works or what is goind wrong (I only get error codes), I am completely lost.

So this question is about setting the record straight.

My application is **not** Web-based, I do **not** make, or see, the Endpoint that responds to my requests.

The application runs in a Citrix Environment, and has to talk to the endpoint on an Intranet. I am not on this intranet myself, we log in to Citrix from a remote location for testing purposes.

Do I have to get the Kerberos Token in my code explicitly, and if so, how (Every method I've seen doesn't work for me).

Do I have to send the Token inside the SAML 2.0 POST Request, and if so where does it fit in the SAML structure?

Comment: SAML is browser based SSO but for non browser based clients there is the ECP profile. Might point you in the right direction although how you integrate it with kerberos isn't stated https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/CONCEPT/ECP

Answer (score 0):

This question is unanswerable. We cannot see into your application, their intranet, or any of the traffic sent across the wire.

Many applications rely on Windows for Kerberos authentication (more specifically Negotiate), and Windows generally does this transparently. In passive, browser-based scenarios the web server will prompt with a 401 error code and a "WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate" header, which the browser understands, and automatically responds with a token.

In active, application-based scenarios, the web service might respond with the same error code, but this is often negotiated ahead of time, and the application knows to manually request a ticket from Windows. Some development frameworks like .NET are designed to also do this automatically for you in many cases.

None of this has anything to do with SAML, but the flow of tokens is basically the same, with the caveat that there's an extra hop where a Kerberos ticket is exchanged for the SAML token. This extra hop is undefined, and is up to a developer to figure out, but can certainly just be a request header when doing the SAMLRequest.

Comment: You say that some development frameworks like .NET are designed to also do this automatically. I am using .NET and nothing is happening automatically. We send a request and get an exception (that we have to catch) saying "401: Unauthorized". Do you have any examples as how to activate this automated operations, and how to use them correcly (as I am obviously not)

Comment: There are a dozen different ways to make web requests in .NET. You really need to provide significantly more detail in your question, and preferably code samples of how this all works, before you get anything useful. There's just too many ways that this could work.